# Can't compile PrimeFaces demo

Tags: maven, jsf, primefaces

I downloaded the PF demo from git at: https://github.com/primefaces/showcase

And run mvn package, but received the following message:

```
 martin@MyUbuntu:~/study/PrimeFaces/showcase$ mvn package
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building primefaces-showcase 6.0-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Downloading: http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/themes/all-themes/1.0.10/all-themes-1.0.10.pom
    Downloaded: http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/themes/all-themes/1.0.10/all-themes-1.0.10.pom (10 KB at 8.7 KB/sec)
    Downloading: http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/themes/themes-project/1.0.10/themes-project-1.0.10.pom
    Downloaded: http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/themes/themes-project/1.0.10/themes-project-1.0.10.pom (4 KB at 8.1 KB/sec)
    Downloading: http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/primefaces/6.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
    Downloading: http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/primefaces/6.0-SNAPSHOT/primefaces-6.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
    [WARNING] The POM for org.primefaces:primefaces:jar:6.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
    Downloading: http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/themes/all-themes/1.0.10/all-themes-1.0.10.jar
    Downloading: http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/primefaces/6.0-SNAPSHOT/primefaces-6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    Downloaded: http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/themes/all-themes/1.0.10/all-themes-1.0.10.jar (1335 KB at 72.0 KB/sec)
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 21.563 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2016-03-08T16:30:14-08:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 11M/153M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project showcase: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.primefaces:showcase:war:6.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.primefaces:primefaces:jar:6.0-SNAPSHOT in prime-repo (http://repository.primefaces.org) -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Answer (score 1):

In your pom.xml file under `<id>dev</id>` fill in the correct version you find at https://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/primefaces/

For the latest build as of today:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
  <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
  <version>6.1.RC2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The pom of the showcase references to an primefaces 6.0 snapshot jar on the primefaces sftp server. 
As far as i can see there is no way to get this jar. I would recomend you to use the prebuild showcase war file and put it on a application server [showcase download](http://www.primefaces.org/downloads)

Comment: You could also suggest to build the 6.0-SNAPSHOT too, locally. Then you have this jar.

Comment: In my case worked downloading not master source but 5.3 version. Then I changed in pom from   5.4-SNAPSHOT to 5.3 and it worked: mvn clean, mvn package and mvn jetty:run